# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009' ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, runtime-error

I need your help please . This error occurs on adding the items in the shopping cart in my classic ASP application (is not always)

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime
error '800a0009'
Subscript out of range
/agrega_carrito.inc, line 71
```

This is the code from file, lines 56 - 86

```
if IsEmpty(Session("arrcarrito")) then
'Create shopping cart
Dim arrcarrito()
Redim arrcarrito(6, 1)
arrcarrito (0, 0) = idprod
arrcarrito (1, 0) = color
arrcarrito (2, 0) = talla
arrcarrito (3, 0) = cantidad
arrcarrito (4, 0) = precio
arrcarrito (5, 0) = peso
Session("arrcarrito") = arrcarrito
Else
'Add items to shopping cart
arrcarrito = Session("arrcarrito")
tamano_arr = Ubound(arrcarrito, 2)
Redim Preserve arrcarrito (6, tamano_arr + 1)   <- line 71
arrcarrito (0, tamano_arr) = idprod
arrcarrito (1, tamano_arr) = color
arrcarrito (2, tamano_arr) = talla
arrcarrito (3, tamano_arr) = cantidad
arrcarrito (4, tamano_arr) = precio
arrcarrito (5, tamano_arr) = peso
Session("arrcarrito") = arrcarrito
end if
arrcart = Session("arrcarrito")
l = 0
r = UBound(arrcart,2) - 1
s = UBound(arrcart,1)
Call QuickSort(arrcart, l, r, 1, s)
Session("arrcarrito") = arrcart
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Works on my machine. It seems from your code you have misunderstood how array bounds work.  In VBScript this `Redim arr(1, 1)` creates a 2 x 2 array with both dimensions having an LBound of 0 and UBound of 1.  This approach is different from other languages where one normally defines a length.  Perhaps if you adjusted your code with that knowledge the problem might go away.  That said I can't see your code failing at the point you indicate and testing a version of it I can't reproduce the problem.  You might also find out what value `tamano_arr` ends being.

Comment: What is the code for `QuickSort`? It might change the array making it something else.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in `Redim Preserve` when either the last dimension value is less than 0 or any of the other dimension values differ from the original value used when the array was first created.

The only reason I can think for your code failing is that some other page has tampered with the session value such that the array returned is not what you expect it to be.

Perhaps another page is written with a better understanding of how arrays work and therefore uses a UBound of 5 for the first dimension since the sixth entry isn't being used?

Comment: The bug is the costumer take a long time to finish the order, on my server I have 300 minutes to the session IIS buy I think is not enough. When the script look for the var arrcarrito this one not exist more and it generate the error. I'm right? Do you think a possible solution to fix it ?

Comment: @alvaroms: I can't see how having the session expire would cause this error.  If the session had expired the code you have included would not reach line 71.

Comment: I think the var arrcarrito doesn't existe because the costumer a take a long delay to finish the adding of items.. is it possible ?

Comment: @alvaroms: No its not possible.  If the variable didn't exist you would get a type mismatch error.

Comment: the last idea I have is var arrcarrito is empty... that's maybe right ?

Comment: @alvaroms: No you would get a type mismatch.